# How to get cookie storage to work with my game

Tags: javascript, html

I Want to be able to save everything in my javascript using cookies but I have no idea how. Is there a special format that let me save while the games open my main.js file so when i switch tabs in my game it doesnt reset. http://prntscr.com/nxqg7y  http://prntscr.com/nxqgac   http://prntscr.com/nxqgc2   it resets everything when i change pages . please dont link me to that owschool page about cookies. I want a working way for my code to keep stuff on one page/js saved and will let those variables effect otehr pages. at the moment on tab change it just resets everything. I also want the storage set up for when I upload this

I've tried this:

```
function getCookie(cname)
{
   var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for (var j = 0; j < ca.length; j++)
    {
       var c = ca[j];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
           c = c.substring(1);
       if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
           return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
     }     
   return "";
   }

   function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays)
  {
       var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
      document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
  }
```

but honestly i dont understand how to make it save my javascripts data for when the game is open. I eventually want it to be localstorage but not now just cookies please.

This is my JavaScript:

```
  var cookies = 0;

function cookieClick() {
    cookies = cookies + Strength;
   document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
    checkCursor()
}
    ///var UP_INTERVAL = 1000; 
 ///setInterval(cookieClick, UP_INTERVAL);


function Bigclick() {
    if (ManaPoints >= 10 && rebirths >= 1) {
        cookies = cookies + 50
       ManaPoints = ManaPoints - 10;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
       document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
   }
   checkCursor()
}

var cursors = 0;

function buyCursor() {
     var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, cursors)); //works out 
 the cost of this cursor
   if (cookies >= cursorCost) { //checks that the player can afford the 
cursor
        cursors = cursors + 1; //increases number of cursors
         cookies = cookies - cursorCost; //removes the cookies spent
         document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors; //updates 
    the number of cursors for the user
         document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies; //updates 
   the number of cookies for the user
       }
        var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, cursors)); //works 
       out   
        the cost of the next cursor
       document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost; //u 
          pdates 
           the cursor cost for the user

     }

  var cats = 0;

  function buyCat() {
    var cursorCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.1, cats)); //works out the 
  cost of this cursor
      if (cookies >= cursorCost) { //checks that the player can afford the 
  cursor
          cats = cats + 2; //increases number of cursors
         cookies = cookies - cursorCost; //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('cats').innerHTML = cats; //updates the 
  number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies; //updates 
  the number of cookies for the user
    }
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, cats)); //works out the 
cost of the next cursor
   document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost; //updates 
the cursor cost for the user
 }

 var rebirths = 0;
 var HitPoints = 0;
 var ManaPoints = 0;
 var SkillPoints = 0;
 var Strength = 1;

  function buyRebirth() {
     var rebirthCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, rebirths));
     if (cookies >= rebirthCost && rebirths < 1) {
       cookies = cookies - rebirthCost
        HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
       ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 10;
       SkillPoints = SkillPoints + 1;
       rebirths = rebirths + 1;
        document.getElementById("rebirths").innerHTML = rebirths;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
       document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
         document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
       document.getElementById("rebirthCost").innerHTML = rebirthCost;
      document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints;
   }
   if (cookies >= rebirthCost)
       if (rebirths >= 1) {
           cookies = cookies - rebirthCost
            rebirths = rebirths + 1;
          SkillPoints = SkillPoints + 1;
            document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
          document.getElementById("rebirthCost").innerHTML = rebirthCost;
          document.getElementById("rebirths").innerHTML = rebirths;
          document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints;

       }
   var nextCost5 = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, rebirths));
    document.getElementById('rebirthCost').innerHTML = nextCost5;

}


 function HitPointsup() {
   if (SkillPoints > 0 && rebirths >= 1) {
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints - 1;
        HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
    }
    document.getElementById('SkillPoints').innerHTML = SkillPoints;
     document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
 }

function ManaPointsup() {
     if (SkillPoints > 0 && rebirths >= 1) {
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints - 1;
         ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 10;
     }
    document.getElementById('SkillPoints').innerHTML = SkillPoints;
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
}

function Strengthup() {
    if (SkillPoints > 0 && rebirths >= 1) {
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints - 1;
        Strength = Strength + 0.5;
    }
   document.getElementById('SkillPoints').innerHTML = SkillPoints;
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
}



function checkCursor() {
   if (cookies <= 9) {
       document.getElementById("cursorCostBtn").disabled = true;
   } else {
       document.getElementById("cursorCostBtn").disabled = false;
    }

   if (cookies <= 49) {
       document.getElementById("catCostBtn").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("catCostBtn").disabled = false;
   }

     if (cookies <= 99) {
        document.getElementById("dogCostBtn").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("dogCostBtn").disabled = false;
    }

   if (cookies <= 199) {
         document.getElementById("humanCostBtn").disabled = true;
   } else {
        document.getElementById("humanCostBtn").disabled = false;
    }

    if (cookies <= 9) {
        document.getElementById("rebirthCostBtn").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("rebirthCostBtn").disabled = false;
    }

    if (rebirths < 1) {
        document.getElementById("BigClickBtn").disabled = true;
    } else {
       document.getElementById("BigClickBtn").disabled = false;
    }
}

function getCookie(cname)
  {
     var name = cname + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
     for (var j = 0; j < ca.length; j++)
     {
         var c = ca[j];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
             c = c.substring(1);
         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
             return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
       return "";
     }

  function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays)
 {
     var d = new Date();
     d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
      document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }
```

Html code:

```
</div>
   <div class="main_container">
        <p>
            <html>

            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
            </head>
           <title> Basic Clicker</title>

            <body>
               <style>
                    div,
                   a {
                       text-align: center;
                   }

                </style>
                <span id="cookies">0</span>
              <br />
            <span id="rebirths">0</span>
            <br />
            <button onclick="cookieClick()">Click Me!</button>
            <br />
            Cost: 10mp <button id="BigClickBtn" onclick="Bigclick()">BigClick</button>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span> <button id="cursorCostBtn" onclick="buyCursor()">Buy Cursor</button>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="catCost">50</span> <button onclick="buyCat()" id="catCostBtn">Buy Cat</button>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="dogCost">100</span> <button onclick="buyDog()" id="dogCostBtn">Buy Dog</button>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="humanCost">200</span> <button onclick="buyHuman()" id="humanCostBtn">Buy Human</button>
            <br />
            Cost: <span id="rebirthCost">10</span> <button onclick="buyRebirth()" id="rebirthCostBtn">Rebirth</button>
            <br />
            Hp:<span id="HitPoints">0</span> Mp:<span id="ManaPoints">0</span> 

        </body>
```

I expect when switching tabs for the data to be stored in cookies and for it not all to get deleted deleted. But the actual output is on tab change everything gets wiped nothing is saved.

Comment: You don't appear to have any cookies at the moment -- just a JavaScript variable called `cookies`. You mention `localStorage`, which is the approach that I would recommend for this -- have you tried anything in that regard?

Comment: no because i don't want it saved permanently yet. i want to be able to close the html browser and for the game to reset. until i am ready to upload it. how would I made what is in the contents of a js file save with cookies. how do I use cookies? u can change that bottom part if u like because im not sure how to set it up.

Comment: You can make use of `sessionStorage`; it's just like `localStorage`, but gets cleared when the session ends.

Comment: `localStorage` isn't permanent. You can easily clear it via the browser dev tools or with a simple bit of js.